# C++ - "Cannot declare parameter 'anonymous' to be of abstract type"

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, abstract

I have this simple class (Alpha) and his abstract class (Beta). I'm unable to pass Alpha (Beta) objects to overwrite() function, because abstract class can't handle self type objects.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;

class Beta {
    public:
        virtual int  read() const = 0;
        virtual void write(int) = 0;
        virtual void overwrite(Beta) = 0; // <-- This is the problem
};

class Alpha : public Beta {
    public:
        int  read     () const;
        void write    (int);
        void overwrite(Alpha);
    private:
        int value;
};

int Alpha::read() const {
    return value;
}
void Alpha::write(int v) {
    value = v;
}
void Alpha::overwrite(Alpha A) {
    value = A.value;
}

int main () {
    Alpha A, B;
    A.write(8);
    B.write(6);

    cout << "A: " << A.read() << endl; // 8
    cout << "B: " << B.read() << endl; // 6

    A.overwrite(B);

    cout << endl << "A: " << A.read(); // 6
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me `[Error] cannot declare parameter '<anonymous>' to be of abstract type 'Beta'`. How to deal with it? It's a small code sample, but I need to solve this because I can't overload operators and declaring that type of functions correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The `Beta` class is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

Your function signature wants an instantiation of an abstract class.

Try passing by reference or pointer:

```
void overwrite(Beta& b);
void overwrite(Beta * b);
```

Comment: I did it, and it showed a different error: 
Cannot declare variable 'A' to be of abstract type 'Alpha' because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Alpha': virtual void Beta::overwrite(Beta&)

Comment: @AndroidGuy Which is exactly what I told you would happen if you didn't change the signature of `Alpha::overwrite`.

Comment: Huh sorry, I didn't get it.

Comment: @AndroidGuy:  Your `Alpha` class is abstract because it doesn't *correctly* implement the `overwrite` method.  The compiler says that `overwrite(Alpha a)` is a different method than `overwrite(Beta& b)`.  Your `Alpha` class needs to have an `overwrite(Beta& b)` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `overwrite` method is pure-virtual and not being overridden. This method has the following signature in `Beta`

```
virtual void overwrite(Beta) = 0;
```

In `Alpha` it is

```
void overwrite(Alpha);
```

These are **not** the same function signature. What you can do is pass a reference and cast it, for example

```
class Beta {
    public:
        virtual int  read() const = 0;
        virtual void write(int) = 0;
        virtual void overwrite(Beta&) = 0;
};

class Alpha : public Beta {
    public:
        int  read     () const;
        void write    (int);
        void overwrite(Beta&) override;  // Note the override
    private:
        int value;
};

void Alpha::overwrite(Beta& A){
    value = static_cast<Alpha&>(A).value;
}
```

This will produce the output ([live demo](http://cpp.sh/5iif)):

```
A: 8
B: 6

A: 6
```

Note that I added the keyword `override` after the function declaration in `Alpha`. If you would have done this while the argument was still an `Alpha`, your code would not have compiled for this reason.

Comment: That's a nice answer, but in my case the Alpha class shouldn't be touched, especially in the case of mentioning the abstract class inside of it. If it could be solved by only touching the abstract class (Beta) it would be very great.

Comment: Then you are SOL. If you cannot change the signature of `overwrite` in your derived class to match the **pure virtual function** in your base class, then you cannot compile any of your derived classes.